# Electron-notarize failing to sign binaries

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, electron

So I've been trying to sign my application for mac os for about a week now to no avail. I've settled on using electron builder. Though my application just keeps erroring. returning this.

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "3891936e-8019-4072-a8ed-28d47c2eee9d",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "SYQEL-VJ.zip",
  "uploadDate": "2021-01-01T01:46:28Z",
  "sha256": "a354f483b08bd240d79a7ae0e019deeca4fcd517b7d673b332e3f31706ecbd8f",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Login Helper",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libffmpeg.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libffmpeg.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/SYQEL-VJ Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Helper",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/SYQEL-VJ Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Helper",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "SYQEL-VJ.zip/SYQEL-VJ.app/Contents/Frameworks/SYQEL-VJ Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/SYQEL-VJ Helper",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

So i've poked around and saw other people had a similar error but nothing i did they suggested has worked.
Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "SYQEL-VJ",
  "description": "SYQEL VJ Application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": {
    "name": "SYQEL LLC",
    "email": "hello@syqel.com",
    "url": "https://www.syqel.com"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.****.****",
    "productName": "SYQEL-VJ",
    "afterSign": "./afterSignHook.js",
    "mac": {
      "icon": "./public/assets/icon.icns",
      "entitlements": "./entitlements.plist",
      "target": [
        "mas"
      ]
    },
    "mas": {
      "hardenedRuntime": false,
      "provisioningProfile": "build/embedded.provisionprofile",
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "asarUnpack": []
    },
    "win": {
      "certificateFile": "./SYQEL.pfx",
      "certificatePassword": "*****!",
      "icon": "build/assets/icon.ico"
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "out"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@iconify/icons-ion": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/react": "^1.1.3",
    "address": "^1.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "butterchurn": "^2.6.7",
    "butterchurn-presets": "^2.4.7",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-settings": "^4.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rescripts start",
    "build": "rescripts build",
    "test": "rescripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "cross-env concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
    "electron-pack": "build -m"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.10",
    "@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.5",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^4.2.12",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

my current aftersign.js

```
// See: https://medium.com/@TwitterArchiveEraser/notarize-electron-apps-7a5f988406db

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var electron_notarize = require('electron-notarize');

module.exports = async function (params) {
    // Only notarize the app on Mac OS only.
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        return;
    }
    console.log('afterSign hook triggered', params);

    // Same appId in electron-builder.
    let appId = 'com.****.****'

    let appPath = path.join(params.appOutDir, `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`);
    if (!fs.existsSync(appPath)) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot find application at: ${appPath}`);
    }

    console.log(`Notarizing ${appId} found at ${appPath}`);

    try {
        await electron_notarize.notarize({
            appBundleId: appId,
            appPath: appPath,
            appleId: "*****@gmail.com",
            appleIdPassword: "***-****-***-****",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    console.log(`Done notarizing ${appId}`);
};
```

and my entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```